# change state for itemRenderer when drag complete

Tags: flex4, itemrenderer

I have a List with dragEnabled = true, and selectionColor = "#ff0000", when the user selects one item, it behaves as what I expect. But when I complete drag and release item, it still remains selected state. What I want is when drag complete, the item back to **normal** state, NOT **selected** state. What I do is that I check if the data **dropComplete** property is true, then change the state, but it can NOT work.

my code is following:

```
override protected function getCurrentRendererState():String {
    currentState = super.getCurrentRendererState();
    if(data.dropComplete) {
        currentState = null;
        data.dromComplete = false;
    }
}
```

select state:

[image]

normal state:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a wrong direction. The solution is really simple, just listen for dragComplete event on List, code below:

```
private function myDragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
    this.selectedIndices = new Vector.<int>;
}
```